# Add grid table to plot

Tags: plotting, labeling, grid-layouts

How can I place a grid at a certain position in a plot?

Example:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
grid = Grid[{{"Function", "Parameter"}, {"Sin[x]", "x"}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

How can I place the grid at a certain position of the plot, so that I get e.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`Epilog`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) and [**`Inset`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html)

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  Epilog ->
   Inset[
    Grid[{
      {"Function", "Parameter"},
      {"Sin[x]", "x"}},
     Frame -> All],
    {4.75, .65}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. With `Epilog -> Inset[grid, Scaled[{0.7, 0.7}]]` I can position the grid relative to the plot (coordinates from 0 to 1). Is it possible to set the size of the grid?

Comment: To change the size of the inset I found only this, e.g: `Epilog -> Inset[Rasterize[grid, ImageSize -> 400], Scaled[{0.7, 0.7}]]`?

Comment: It is possible do this with `Listplot`? Because `Listplot` not have `Epilog`.

Comment: @LMC - "`ListPlot` has the same options as `Graphics`, with the following additions and changes: ..."  `Graphics` takes the option `Epilog`.  `ListPlot[data, Epilog -> Inset[grid, pos]]` works for me.

Comment: I had not tried it. I am grateful.